# I am unable to form table in struts 2 tags for java List<.String>

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 tags, i unable to create table using struts 2 tags for the following code

```
    List<String> list_Fields;
    List<QueryResult> iteratorquery;
    List<String> List_rows;

    for (int i = 0; i < iteratorquery.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(iteratorquery.get(i));
        QueryResult list_result = iteratorquery.get(i);
        System.out.println(list_result.getFields());
        list_Fields = list_result.getFields();
        servletRequest.setAttribute("list", list_Fields);
        for (int g = 0; g < list_Fields.size(); g++) {
            System.out.println("Hello ListOFFields:" + list_Fields.get(g));
        }

        List_rows = list_result.getRows();
        for (int h = 0; h < List_rows.size(); h++) {
            System.out.println(List_rows.get(h));
            String rowList = List_rows.get(h);
            System.out.println("Hello i am in Rows:" + rowList);
        }
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ??

Answer (score 0):

I already answered similar question on SO.Do something like this on your JSP

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="list" status="listStatus">
  <tr>
    <s:if test="#listStatus.even == true">
      <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property/></td>
    </s:if>
    <s:elseif test="#listStatus.first == true">
      <td><s:property/> (This is first value) </td>
    </s:elseif>
    <s:else>
      <td><s:property/></td>
    </s:else>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

For more detail refer to the following question on SO

[Table creation using Struts2 tag and Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063149/i-am-unable-to-form-table-in-liststring-using-struts-2-tags/8063550#comment9878834_8063550)

**edit**

```
List<QueryResult> iteratorquery;
```

i believe that `QueryResult` is your object which contains the results as i am not sure about `QueryResult` structure.
so when we iterate the  `List<QueryResult>` using struts2 iterator tag it will place the `QueryResult` object on the value stack.

Accessing Object and its properties from values stack is all your choice you can use OGNL to access you properties inside the value stack.

e.g
If `QueryResult` has two prperty

```
-name
-age
```

you can refer them inside your iterator something like

```
<s:iterator value="iteratorquery" var="queryResult">
   <s:property value="#queryResult.name" />
       <s:property value="#queryResult.age" />
 </s:iterator>
```

Hope this will help additionally i will suggest you to read the basic of struts2 request flow cycle as well how OGNL find values on value stack

[OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ognl-basics.html)

Comment: sorry its not like that , see the above code it is List<String> there is no if condition to check , please go through it, In my above the is two for loop inside on outer for loop, i asking help

Comment: the above method is with java code i want to iterate List<String> literally what i have done in java. I am facing here like  iteratorquery.get(i); in that code , Will u please tell me how can i get i of element in strut tag.

Comment: let me also explain the class object queryResult and its structure, queryResult contain List<String> result each result represents each query result 

Thank You

Comment: How to iterate following using struts2 
for(LinkedHashMap<Object,Object> map : list_Fields){
                    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        Object key = entry.getKey();
                        Object value = entry.getValue();
                        System.out.println("Hello Col:"
                 + key);
                        System.out.println("Hello Rows:"
                 + value);
                              //Your code
                    }
                }

Comment: @MohanMaverick;linkedhashMap is also "Map" so you can iterate that the same way we do for Map. Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184222/how-to-retrieve-value-from-linkedhashmap-using-iterators-in-struts2

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.

At the very least, you're overwriting the value of the "list" request attribute.

As far as I can tell, the Java code boils down to the following, and you want to write that using S2 tags.

```
List<QueryResult> queryResults;
for (QueryResult result : queryResults) {
    List<String> fields = result.getFields();
    for (String field : fields) {
        System.out.println("field: " + field);
    }

    List<String> rows = result.getRows();
    for (String row : rows) {
        System.out.println("row: " + row);
    }
}
```

If that's the case, strictly using S2 tags, you'd expos `queryResults` to the JSP via a normal S2 action property, and end up with something like the following:

```
<s:iterator value="queryResults" var="iq">
    <s:iterator value="iq.fields">
        <s:property />
    </s:iterator>

    <s:iterator value="id.rows">
        <s:property />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

As Umesh says, you can play some fun games with the iterators to help style your results, although you can do it more concisely using OGNL and a minimal amount of CSS.

```
<s:iterator value="results" status="status">
  <tr class="fields">
    <s:iterator value="fields">
      <td><s:property /></td>
    </s:iterator>
  </tr>

  <s:set var="rowsStyle" value="#status.last ? 'last' : ''" />
  <tr class="<s:property value='#rowsStyle'/>">
    <s:iterator value="rows" status="rowStat">
      <s:set var="tdStyle" value="#rowStat.last ? 'last' : ''" />
      <td class="<s:property value='#tdStyle'/>"><s:property /></td>
    </s:iterator>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thank you and i have problem in iterating field and row value ,you used var for iterator but it showing error for me , so i used id for that like follows
 <s:iterator value="queryResults" id="iq">
         <s:iterator value="iq.fields">
I can able to debug this code but it not displaying rows and fields can please help me .
         <s:property />
         </s:iterator>

         <s:iterator value="iq.rows">
         <s:property />
         </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator>