# Issue in iterating with struts2 tags

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to struts2 i facing problem in iterating List.I am unable to iterate the following code using struts 2 iterator tags and display in table.

```
List<QueryResult> queryResults = queriesresult.getQueryResult();
for (QueryResult q_list : queryResults) {
    List<LinkedHashMap> list_Cols = q_list.getRows();
    for (LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> map : list_Cols) {
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Object key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Hello Col:" + key);
            System.out.println("Hello Rows:" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am exposing queryResults,In JSP I tried:

```
<s:iterator value="queryResults" id="qr">
  <s:iterator value="qr.rows" id="keyrow"> 
    <s:iterator value="keyrow"> <table><tr><td>
      <s:property value="key" />
      <s:property value="value" /> </table></tr></td>
    </s:iterator> 
  </s:iterator> 
</s:iterator>
```

This is what I have tried to iterate in struts but it's not iterating.

Comment: Shall we know what you tied? The tags which you tried using?

Comment: <s:iterator value="queryResults" id="qr">
         <s:iterator value="qr.rows" id="keyrow">
           <s:iterator value="keyrow.entrySet" id="k">
              <s:property value="k.getKey" />
              <s:property value="k.getvalue" />
           </s:iterator>
         </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator> this how i tried but not able to iterate

Comment: No compilation error in above `Java code`?

Comment: @lschin  yes there no compilation error in that code

Comment: @MohanMaverick: you already asked similar question earlier. i hope you got answer there or not here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090320/i-am-unable-to-form-table-in-struts-2-tags-for-java-list-string

Comment: @umeshawasthi not exactly , this different question please go through it .

Comment: What exactly `QueryResult` is ?

Comment: are you adding the queryResults list to the model of the jsp page?

Comment: I already gone through it and there is not much difference how you can query and iterate through a list and LinkedhashMap.All concept revolves around how request flow goes moreover if you try to find out how to iterate inside java code you have already asked question and got the response.better come up what you tried a=using struts2 and its tag where you are facing problem rather than asking direct answer

Comment: <s:iterator value="queryResults" id="qr">
         <s:iterator value="qr.rows" id="keyrow">
          <s:iterator value="keyrow.entrySet">
           <s:property value="key" />
           <s:property value="value" />
          </s:iterator>
         </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator> this is what i have tried to iterate in struts bot not iterating

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<s:iterator value="queryResults" id="qr"> <s:iterator value="qr.rows" id="keyrow">

Value : <s:property value="keyrow['<<key>>']"/>
</s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

a map value can be accessed by using the format mapName['key'].

Comment: is the map being iterated?, please put something there to identify that the map is actually being iterated through. (do you see `Value :  ` displayed multiple times)?

Comment: no the map not iterated Anantha Sharma .I debugged it not iterating

Answer (score 0):

For Struts 2.1+ you should use `var` to define each iteration object's name, not `id`.

The inner-most `<s:iterator>` tag should iterate over `keyrow`, *not* `keyrow.entrySet`.

Besides that it's redundant (a map iterator already iterates over the map's entry set), in OGNL it will look for a property named `entrySet`--but that's not a *property* of a map, it's a *method*: `keyrow.entrySet()`. But it's unnecessary anyway.

Comment: sorry , its still not working

        <s:iterator value="queryResults" id="qr">
         <s:iterator value="qr.rows" id="keyrow">
          <s:iterator value="keyrow">
           <table><tr>
           <th>
           <s:property value="key" />
           <s:property value="value" />
           </th>
           </tr>
           </table>
          </s:iterator>
         </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator> Please Help me

Comment: @MohanMaverick How do you expect me to read that? Update your question, describe the data, describe what's exposed by the action.

Comment: sorry its cant be editable and i only changed as what you said instead of keyrow.entrySet(), i used have changed to  keyrow thats it .